# MYSQL SELECT trouble (AND operator on on column)

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to the following:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | Order| SalesMan |
+----+------+----------+
| 1  | 1001 |     1    |
| 2  | 1001 |     2    |
| 3  | 1002 |     1    |
| 4  | 1002 |     4    |
| 5  | 1003 |     2    |
+----+------+----------+
```

I want to select the the orders sharing multiple Sales Men with an AND operator. Like showing only orders made by Salesmen 1 & 2.

Comment: You mean showing only orders made by SalesMan 1 OR 2?

Comment: No, Showing only orders made by SalesMen 1 AND 2

Comment: @SalahAbuElgassim check my answer below, it may solve your problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A/c to what i understand about your question, there will be one order with multiple entries of salesman associated. If you just have to know about those orders which salesman 1 and 2 both are associated with then,you can do something like this:

```
   SELECT `order` 
   FROM tbl 
   WHERE salesMan=1 
   AND `order` 
   IN (select `order` from tbl where salesMan=2)
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28a812/12) for better understanding..

**EDIT:** I have changed the query a/c to your need:

```
SELECT orders 
FROM tbl 
WHERE salesMan 
IN (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY orders 
HAVING count(orders)>1;
```

check the [fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46e0e/7) here

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` Clause.

### Query

```
SELECT salesMan
FROM tbl
GROUP BY salesMan
HAVING COUNT(salesMan) > 1;
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e65fc/3)

Comment: Selecting two SalesMen is just an example. Counting does not solve the problem.

Comment: Then how do you want the output. Just mention it properly in the question. like add expected output

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i've just modified the example table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE SalesMan IN(1,2);
```